# Excel using index based on sheet name

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am using the following formula to look up a table and return values that have a number in the corresponding column, but instead of column c, I want it to be based on the sheet name.

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Look Up Table'!$B$2:$B$48,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER('Look Up Table'!$C$2:$C$48),ROW('Look Up Table'!$C$1:$C$47),""),ROW('Look Up Table'!B3))),"")`

I have a drop down that has the sheet names, which are the same in the look up table.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($G$8:$I$8=$B$1)*($F$9:$F$13=B2),$G$9:$I$13)
```

and drop down:

This is my sample:

[image]

[image]

**Display blank:**

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($G$8:$I$8=$B$1)*($F$9:$F$13=B2),$G$9:$I$13)=0,"",SUMPRODUCT(($G$8:$I$8=$B$1)*($F$9:$F$13=B2),$G$9:$I$13))
```

[image]

Comment: Can this formula skip over the items that are blank, instead of displaying 0.

Comment: Use this formula: **=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($G$8:$I$8=$B$1)*($F$9:$F$13=B2),$G$9:$I$13)=0,"",SUMPRODUCT(($G$8:$I$8=$B$1)*($F$9:$F$13=B2),$G$9:$I$13))**